# Similarity of products $AB$ and $BA$ of square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:$ A_{n\times n} , B_{n\times n} .$

Is it necessary true that there is similarity between $AB$ and $BA$?

I'm not quite sure how to check it is true for every non-singular M matrix. $M^{-1}ABM = BA$

Anyone have any ideas what am I missing to understand in similarity? If it's not necessary true then give a counter example.

Comment: Note that it is true when $A$ or $B$ is non-singular. If WLOG $A$ is nonsingular, $AB=AB(AA^{-1})=A(BA)A^{-1}$

Comment: @G.T.R If A or B is non-singular it will be similar for $A^{-1}$

Comment: To say that $C$ and $D$ are similar does not mean that for EVERY matrix $M$ we have $C = M^{-1}DM$.  It means that for SOME matrix $M$, that holds.  "For some" means at least one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, then $AB = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $BA = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
It is clear that $MBAM^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \neq AB$ for every invertible matrix $M$.

Comment: With pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

While @Surb has given a counter-example, we do have the following result when $A$ or $B$ are singular (or even not square matrices):

Suppose that $AB$ and $BA$ are both square matrices and $\lambda$ is a non-zero eigenvalue of $AB$.  Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$.

*Proof:* Suppose $ABv=\lambda v$.  Then $BA(Bv)=B(ABv)=B(\lambda v)=\lambda(Bv)$.  Since $ABv\neq 0$, we have $Bv\neq 0$, and so $Bv$ is an $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $BA$.

In fact, more can be said: up to a factor of $t^k$ (which is necessary to correct degree issues when $A$ and $B$ are not square), $AB$ and $BA$ will have the same characteristic polynomials.  And, since $B(AB-\lambda)^k=(BA-\lambda)^kB$, we have a matchup not just of eigenvalues, but of approximate eigenvalues as well, and so the only obstruction to $AB$ and $BA$ being similar lies in their generalized zero-eigenspaces.

So again, while @Surb has showed that the matrices need not be similar, the problems that can occur are of a very limited nature.